# Item cannot be cast to com.example.sharingapp.Contact

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am working on Android app code and I have extended the `ArrayAdapter` class and I am getting this **error** message

`Item cannot be cast to com.example.sharingapp.Contact`

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.sharingapp;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
        super(context, 0, contacts);
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // getItem(position) gets the "contact" at "position" in the "contacts" ArrayList
        // (where "contacts" is a parameter in the ContactAdapter creator as seen above ^^)
        Contact contact =  getItem(position);

        String username = "Username: " + contact.getUsername();
        String email = "Email: " + contact.getEmail();

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view.
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contactlist_contact, parent, false);
        }

        TextView username_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username_tv);
        TextView email_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.email_tv);
        ImageView photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_image_view);

        photo.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);

        username_tv.setText(username);
        email_tv.setText(email);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The error refers to the line:

`Contact contact =  getItem(position);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a list of "Contact" inside your adapter.

You need something like:

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And, after that, on your constructor:

```
    public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
       super(context, 0, contacts);
       this.context = context;
       this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
       this.contactsList = contacts;
    }
```

Then override "getItem" to return Contact from your "conctactList" with given position:

```
    @Override
    public Contact getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return contacts.get(position);
    }
```

Comment: The issue is not resolved it is giving me the same error still.

Comment: for the line return contacts.get(position) it is giving me the error contacts cannot be resolved.

Comment: i have tried by replacing contacts with contactList and now it is giving me the same error for the two different line return contactList.get(position) and in the Contact contact = getItem(position).

Comment: Thank you for all the help you have done. i have solved the issue that occured .

Answer (score 0):

This is a codebase from the Coursera course, Object-Oriented Design.

I had a similar issue and I solved this by fixing code in **ContactList** class **loadContacts** method, need to set correct type of **ArrayList** after copying this method from **ItemList** class.